# I Get an error every time I create a table column and hit save

Tags: mysql

I am using PhpMyAdmin to create a database for the website I am going to build and so. I created a database, then I created a table inside & the next step is creating the columns. 
After I gave the name of the columns give them type and length for every column. I hit save. 
But the error shows up. which your gonna see below then I ignore that and it creates it anyway. But i don't know what problem could it cause in the future meaning after i started my php coding

[image: PhpMyAdminInterface]
Error

```
bl_structure.php#47: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->indexAction()
Warning in .\templates\table\structure\display_table_stats.phtml#4
 Illegal string offset 'TABLE_COMMENT'

Backtrace

.\libraries\Template.php#152: include(.\templates\table\structure\display_table_stats.phtml)
.\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController.php#1389: PMA\libraries\Template->render(array)
.\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController.php#1265: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
.\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController.php#355: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
array,
array,
)
.\tbl_structure.php#47: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->indexAction()
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the table? where are you doing that?

Comment: How do you mean ? I am using xampp server and it have an embedded Mysql database and you just create database table and the like right?

Comment: I imagine you are using some kind of GUI like PhpMyAdmin or something like that, can you show us a photo of what you have?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nCGn4lpJT5klnfk2uS9dN3oDtfIO57xp

Comment: this the link to the image you asked for

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a String to your properties, you need to change the value type to varchar to be able to add Strings. For example item_name is an int(11) and you need it to be varchar(255) for example